# Derivative of the trace of a product

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I would like to compute the following. How can I do this?

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial X}\text{Tr} \big( X \log X \big)$$

Or, more generally, how to compute derivatives of the following form?

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial X}\text{Tr} \big( f(X) g(X) \big)$$

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the scalar function and its first derivative
$$\eqalign{
 h(s) &= f(s)g(s) \cr
 h' &= fg'+gf' \cr
}$$
Your general function applies this scalar function to a matrix argument, i.e. $H=h(X),\,$ then takes the trace. So the function, differential and gradient are given by 
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= {\rm tr}(H) \cr
d\phi &= {\rm tr}(H'\,dX) \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= H' = \,\,f(X)g'(X)+g(X)f'(X) \cr
}$$
Depending on your preferred layout convention, the gradient may be transposed.